# Correct way to use IReactiveDerivedList as a user types a filter term in

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have a root list of strings in a `ReactiveList<string>`

```
private ReactiveList<string> Items { get; set; }
```

and a derived list

```
private IReactiveDerivedList<string> _FilteredItems;
public IReactiveDerivedList<string> FilteredItems{ get => _FilteredItems; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _FilteredItems, value); }
```

I also have a filter term that changes as a user types into a `TextBox`

```
private string _FilterTerm;
public string FilterTerm { get => _FilterTerm; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _FilterTerm, value); }
```

Finally, I use the following in my constructor which **recreates** the derived list each time `FilterTerm` changes

```
this.WhenAnyValue(This => This.FilterTerm).Where(filterTerm => filterTerm != null).Subscribe((filterTerm) =>
{
    FilteredItems = Items.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, x => x.Contains(FilterTerm));
});
```

... Am I doing this correctly, or is there a better way as this feels a bit like 'I could just create a new `ReactiveList` each time, why bother with the `IReactiveDerivedList`'?

---

**UPDATE**

I've found the following example, which almost works for me, https://janhannemann.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/reactiveui-goodies-ireactivederivedlist-filtering-2/, but it requires that I add an `IsFiltered` property to my ViewModel, but in this case, I'm not using a ViewModel, I'm just using a `string`!

Comment: We've deprecated the ReactiveList/IReactiveDerivedList in favour of DynamicData, see https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/ for details. Slightly different way of doing things, but way more powerful/flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment. ReactiveUI framework has deprecated the ReactiveList in favour of DynamicData https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/

If you were going to achieve this in DynamicData you would do the following:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using DynamicData;

public class FilteringClass
{
   private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> _filteredItems;
   private readonly SourceList<string> _items = new SourceList<string>();
   private string _filterTerm;

   public FilteringClass(IEnumerable<string> items)
   {
      var filterTermChanged = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FilterTerm);
      _items.AddRange(items);
      _items.Connect()
         // This will update your output list whenever FilterTerm changes.
         .AutoRefreshOnObservable(_ => filterTermChanged)
         // This is similar to a Where() statement.
         .Filter(x => FilterTerm == null || x.Contains(FilterTerm))
         // SourceList is thread safe, this will make your output list only be updated on the main thread.
         .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
         // This will make the FilteredItem's be updated with our data.
         .Bind(out _filteredItems)
         // This is a observable, so Subscribe to start the goodness.
         .Subscribe();

   }

   public string FilterTerm
   {
      get => _filterTerm;
      set => RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _filterTerm, value);
   }

   public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> FilteredItems => _filteredItems;
}
```

Comment: You can also use a ObservableCollection<string> or ObservableCollectionExtended<string>, if you use those be aware they aren't thread safe and you use the `ToObservableChangeSet()` method instead of `Connect()`. `SourceList<T>` is mean't to be private inside your class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did look at DynamicData but I was 'in a rush' and thought there might be a bit of a steep learning curve. I now see that it's worth the effort :0)

Comment: I just tried this, but I'm getting a compilation error on `.AutoRefresh(x => x.FilterTerm)` ... **"'string' does not contain a definition for 'FilterTerm' and no accessible extension method 'FilterTerm' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found"** ... which makes sense as `x` is a `string`! I'm stuck on how to reference `FilteringClass.FilterTerm` within the `AutoRefresh(...)` expression?

Comment: I modified the answer. Sorry AutoRefresh() works on a property on the object stored in the collection, you have to use AutoRefreshOnObservable() otherwise.

Comment: So the way AutoRefreshOnObservable() works is it's a Lambda, the parameter is the individual item in the items, and you return an observable which when signalled will cause that item to be re-evaluated. In this case since you want all items to be re-evaluated you ignore the parameter and just return the observable to the FilterTerm change event.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Don't know if you just saw my stupid comment?! ... I had missed the `var filterTermChanged = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FilterTerm);` line you had added, and just put the Lambda directly into the auto refresh bit, eg ... `.AutoRefreshOnObservable(_ => this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FilterTerm))`. Works a treat!

Comment: Yeah the reason why I put it into a variable first it just avoids generating n WhenAnyValue instances

Comment: Ahh! Must be nice to be an expert ;0) Thanks again.